# Why do i get the extention of the file in the file name ? And how do i filter the List<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

All the files are .avi
but what i get in the List is this format: test.avi 0.1 MB

And it should be: test.avi 0.1MB

```
files = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\")
    .GetFiles("*.avi")
    .Where(f => f.Length <= maximumfilessize * 1024 * 1024)
    .Select(f => f.Name + " " + Math.Round(((double)f.Length / 1048576d), 1) + " MB")
    .ToList();
```

Next thing i did was:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
    long filesize = new FileInfo(@"d:\" + files[i]).Length;               
}
```

Somehow i want to check that if the filesize is less then 1MB then show in the files List the file in the format: test.avi 0.1MB with one number after the point.

But if the filesize is large then 1MB so show the file in the files List in this format: 12MB without the number after the point.

How do i check for the size and how do i change the items in the List ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the extension you can use the [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and to get different formats according to size, you can use a "helper" function and avoid the `Where` filtering:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program {

    static string FileSizeDisplay(FileInfo f) {
        int maximumfilessize= 1;
        const int MB = 1024 * 1024;
        if (f.Length <= maximumfilessize * MB) {
            return Math.Round(((double)f.Length / MB), 1).ToString() + " MB";
        }
        return ((int)f.Length / MB) + " MB";
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\")
            .GetFiles("*.avi")
            .Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name) + " " + FileSizeDisplay(f))
            .ToList();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `test.avi 0.1 MB` because there is a space in your code here

> .Select(f => f.Name + " " + Math.Round(((double)f.Length / 1048576d), 1) + **" MB"**)

To achieve the different format for "big" and "small" files, you simply need to test it. For example like this (minimal changes of your code done):

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\")
    .GetFiles("*.avi")
    .Where(f => f.Length <= maximumfilessize * 1024 * 1024)
    .Select(f => f.Name + " " + (f.Length > 1024 * 1024 ? Math.Round(((double)f.Length / 1048576d), 0) : Math.Round(((double)f.Length / 1048576d), 1)) + "MB")
    .ToList();
```

To get file name without extension use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name)` instead of `f.Name`